# How can I vectorize a loop over a Pandas DataFrame in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, vectorization

I need to make this code run fast by vectorization

```
final1 = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in demo1.iterrows():
    a = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000, p=[1 - row['prob'], row['prob']])
    b = a * row['syb'] * (1 + row['percentage_change_syb'] / 100)
    final1 = final1.append(pd.DataFrame(b).T)
```

Comment: please provide your dataset on which you are looping.

Comment: demo1 = pd.DataFrame({"syb" : [298, 388, 267, 746, 645], "prob" : [0.84, 0.46, 0.68, 0.35, 0.95], "percentage_change_syb" : [1.29, 3.45, 20, 14.9, 12.5]})

Comment: _Above is the data frame_

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not supply data to work against, the following code is unchecked, but should work:

```
def computation(prob, syb, percentage_change_syb):
    a = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=1000, p=[1 - prob, prob])
    b = a * syb * (1 + percentage_change_syb / 100)
    return b.T

final1 = computation(demo1['prob'].values, demo1['syb'].values, demo1['percentage_change_syb'].values)
```

For more information on the choice of operating on NumPy arrays I recommend [this article](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6).

Comment: demo1 = pd.DataFrame({"syb" : [298, 388, 267, 746, 645], "prob" : [0.84, 0.46, 0.68, 0.35, 0.95], "percentage_change_syb" : [1.29, 3.45, 20, 14.9, 12.5]})

Comment: _Above is the data frame_ 
I tried your code . It is giving an error - **ValueError: object too deep for desired array**